# Can I get the name of the checked out tag in the post-checkout hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-tag

I have to write a script to log to Hipchat every time a new tag is deployed in production, but using the post-checkout hook, I only know how to get the SHA1.

Is it possible to retrieve the tag name in the post-checkout hook?

Comment: You could easily use `git for-each-ref` to find a list of refs that point to that particular SHA. But it's entirely possible you could come up with more than one result (or no results), so you'd need to be able to handle that...